# Synchronize Dataset - Multiple users, multiple timestamps

Tags: android, ios, dataset, timestamp, pandas

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to go about doing this:

Basically I will have a bunch of Android/iOS users who will be logging sensor data on their phone, except each user will have its own timestamp depending on when people start the app etc. So say I have two users:

```
User 1: (5,45), (6,34), (8,32)
User 2: (5,35), (7,32), (9,32)
```

The format is (time t, and some arbitrary value).

What would be the best way to synchronize the two datasets? Do I have to write an algorithm which is then going to go back and say on User 2, insert the following entry (6,35). So eventually the new data looks like:

```
User 1: (5,45), (6,34), (7,34), (8,32), (9,32)
User 2: (5,35), (6,35), (7,32), (8,32), (9,32)
```

This could be very data intensive though, because I am expecting to have about 300 users, and each will have about 36,000 data entries. Any advice would be appreciated - also something I could do on the app side that could help that would be appreciated.

I believe I am going to have to do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686272/combining-multiple-timeseries-data-to-one-2d-numpy-array) when I have all my data - but since this is an actively developing project I thought I'd get some advice first.

Comment: Why does your desired output have an entry for (6,35) and (7,34)?  I don't see them in the original data.  Is the value simply propagated from the most recent observation?

Comment: Correct, I was just going to propagate the data forward. The actual collected data is GPS coordinates, and Acceleration reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `DataFrame` from each user's data. Then store them all in a `Panel`.  Pandas will line them all up based on the timestamp and you can use the forward fill method, `ffill`, to propagate the values:

```
In [62]: df1 = DataFrame([45,34,32], index=[5,6,8], columns=['value'])

In [63]: df2 = DataFrame([35,32,32], index=[5,7,9], columns=['value'])

In [64]: p = Panel({'user1': df1, 'user2': df2})

In [75]: p.ffill().to_frame().unstack()
Out[75]:
       user1  user2
minor  value  value
major
5         45     35
6         34     35
7         34     32
8         32     32
9         32     32
```

Or, you could do the same thing using just Series and DataFrames.  I guess it depends on what you want to do with it:

```
In [78]: s1 = Series([45,34,32], index=[5,6,8])

In [79]: s2 = Series([35,32,32], index=[5,7,9])

In [80]: df = DataFrame([s1,s2])

In [81]: df
Out[81]:
    5   6   7   8   9
0  45  34 NaN  32 NaN
1  35 NaN  32 NaN  32

In [82]: df = DataFrame([s1,s2]).T

In [83]: df
Out[83]:
    0   1
5  45  35
6  34 NaN
7 NaN  32
8  32 NaN
9 NaN  32

In [84]: df.ffill()
Out[84]:
    0   1
5  45  35
6  34  35
7  34  32
8  32  32
9  32  32
```